# How to fetch a nested resource tree and render view when all is loaded in backbone.js?

Tags: javascript, rest, backbone.js

**Background**

I have this structure from a restful api:

```
/channels/
/channel/{channelId}/
/channel/{channelId}/programs
```

In my **backbone.js** I have a collection `Channels` and two models, `Channel` and `Program`.

**Problem**

How can I easily fetch a nested model structure, and call a render function in my `ProgramGuideView` when all content is loaded?

**What I have so far**

So far I'm able to fetch the channels, but I don't come up with any good way to fetch the programs for each channel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look into this:

http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#FAQ-nested

This is a very simple approach for having nested models and collections, but can be tuned to support any of your needs. If you need more sophisticated relational management then you should consider using a plugin like this:

https://github.com/PaulUithol/Backbone-relational

Comment: Broken links to documentcloud. Perhaps intended for the move to Backbone's own docs? http://backbonejs.org/#FAQ-nested